# Android market filtering XLarge Screen

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

I am going to upload an app but the UI is not compatible with xlarge tablet. So I want androidMarket to filter out xlarge screen from compatible device.

In My androidmanifest.xml, I use as below. So that android market will filter out Large & XLarge screen. But It doesn't filter as I wanted. Any suggestion?

```
   <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="7" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

Comment: Clear your question. Do you want to remove large screen and X-large screen devices?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

< uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="7"
 />

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
   />
```